# Filling multiple HTML tables from a database table filled by CSV

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, html-table

I currently have a site that has a simple interface where the user logs in and either chooses to Upload or View. They can upload a CSV (for this purpose, the CSV template is around 300 fields) or go to a page to select or search for a particular record that's already been uploaded (sorted by certain keys).

In my folder is an HTML page for the file upload/submit section that utilizes an upload.php file, which is around 400 lines of code that handle the insertion of the CSV into the database. I've now created a display.html file that has about 300 other lines of code for 14 or 15 separate HTML tables on one page. I've created them in HTML first because they each have different styles, headers and formats that need to be kept.

My goal is this: When the user selects a record, I need to display the html page with all the different tables, and each table needs to be filled by certain fields in the SQL staging table that holds the 300 field CSV. So, the first ten fields will be in one table, the next 7 in one, and so on. I know I can't call PHP within an HTML page, but I've created the tables in HTML so I'm wondering if I can change it to php and add certain syntax to the existing table and how I would insert those fields into each table row by name. Here is an example of the upload PHP where I've declared variables for the columns:

PHP (For Uploads-Separate file)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");

$coldata = array();

$coldata[ "orderNumber" ] = $filesop[0];
$coldata[ "place" ] = $filesop[1];
$coldata[ "workOrderNum" ] = $filesop[2];
$coldata["lowSideMIUNum"] = $filesop[3];
$coldata["highSideMIUNum"] = $filesop[4];
$coldata["accountNum"] = $filesop[5];
$coldata["custName"] = $filesop[6];
$coldata["address"] = $filesop[7];
$coldata["locID"] = $filesop[8];
$coldata["date"] = $filesop[9];
$coldata["utility"] = $filesop[10];
$coldata["serialNumber"] = $filesop[11];
$coldata["serviceName"] = $filesop[12];
$coldata["address2"] = $filesop[13];
$coldata["servicePreformed"] = $filesop[14];
$coldata["bypassSize"] = $filesop[15];
}
```

HTML for Existing Tables (Only one table. I left the PHP in the file from my attempt at using it as a PHP file):

```
<!--<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "root";
$db = "uwsTest";

$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM staging";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query1);

if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo'success!';
}


?>


<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
?>
<!--Qa Table-->
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Qa/Qc CheckList</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service Address Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service Loc Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Number Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Manufacturer Changed</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Type Changed</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Model Changed</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Low Register Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>High Register Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['orderNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>

<?
}
?>
```

I left the PHP code in with the table to show what I attempted, but I don't think the naming convention on the table names worked with my php. On my web page I only get me message for a successful db connection but my tables don't show like they did when I ran it only as PHP. What is the best way to insert variables from my database into multiple tables on this page?

Comment: What errors were you getting when you attempted the example provided?

Comment: TMI. I lost interest half way.

Comment: Kade M., No errors but when I executed the HTML file as only tables they all show up. Otherwise, with the PHP code, I get my debug message for successful connection and a blank page otherwise.

Comment: CodeGodie, I've had some issues in the past with the CSV half of this project and I suffered from not putting enough info in the question. I've learned to put as much as needed for the point I'm trying to accomplish, as I'd rather put too much than not enough.

Comment: some of the code is in the comment are you using that code if yes, you are mixing mysql and mysqli in this line `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){`

Comment: ok if i understand you question correctly, your code is working fine, as loong as you use the extention php, but not with html?? if yes why not create an Ajax call, and load the file

Comment: Actually, I have the original display.html that only creates the empty html tables with the styles and headers. However, to fill them, I changed the extension to php to try that code above and it doesn't work. So I'm trying to use PHP to fill the existing tables, or at least, the easiest way to recreate the tables with PHP using the staging table to supply the fields

Comment: you are doing some thing wrong in your php code than, as i mention you are mixing mysql with mysqli here or may be not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139920/discussion-between-h-norman-and-arif-suhail-123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution would allow you to configure which columns appear in which table.

```
<?php

$tables = array();
$tables[0] = array('title' => 'Qa/Qc CheckList', 'cols' => array('Order #' => 'orderNumber','Place' => 'place','Work Order' => 'workOrderNum'));
$tables[1] = array('title' => 'Another CheckList', 'cols' => array('Low Side MIU' => 'lowSideMIUNum','Account #' => 'accountNum','Name' => 'custName'));
// ... add other table definitions ...

if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo'success!';
}
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM staging";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query1);

$all_rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result1);

if($all_rows) {
    foreach($tables as $tableno => $tableinfo) {
        foreach($all_rows as $rowno => $row) {
?>
<!-- <?php echo $tableinfo['title']; ?> -->
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2"><?php echo $tableinfo['title']; ?></th>
</tr>
<?php
            foreach($tableinfo as $col_label => $col_name) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $col_label; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[$col_name]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
            } // end of foreach $table_info
?>
</table>
<?php
        } // end of foreach $all_rows
?>
<?php
    } // end of foreach $tables

} else {
    echo "<p>No data found.</p>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: This makes sense as well. I modified my code from above so that everything uses 'mysql' and I got that working, I just had to call each variable at the right row. If I were to keep that format, everything will always display in the same cells, it's just a matter of selecting the right record from the database. Say I fill a dropdown with each work order number from the database and it's selected, is there a particular way I would call the appropriate record from the database with PHP?

Comment: First of all, use _mysqli_ instead of _mysql_. The former is current, the latter is depreciated. As for the second question, your SQL statement should have a where clause to select the correct record from the table.

Comment: Thank you, My mac actually autocorrected that but I did in fact change them to both use mysqli.

Comment: And the _where_ clause?